# Load data url via new function which saves in a variable - angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to load data from a link by clicking on a button in Angular. I am just 2 days into Angular and really don't know much about it.

I want to click on a button so that it loads json data but instead of loading the URL, it needs to load a new function which gets the URL and saves it to a variable.

This is just my regular button, which opens the URL.

```
<a href="https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Auser">
            <button> Click </button>
        </a>
```

How can I also show it on the console?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Angular's HttpClient to make a request to the URL when the button is clicked.

First of all you need to do is implement HtppClient in your module like example below.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        // other imports ...
        HttpClientModule
      ],
    })
    export class NameOfYourModule { }
```

After that you need to import httpClient in consturcot of your component. Add click function to your button with function loadData(). So if you click on that button. It will call your function and via subscribe recive the data from your specific url.

You can replace console.log with some property to store the data or just check it in developer tools.

Btw: I add that html element button right into the template. You should have it inside HTML. Just replace your button with `<button (click)="loadData()">Click</button>`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-name',
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadData()">Click</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./name.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadData() {
    this.http.get<any>('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Auser').subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        // here you can save data to a variable
        // this.myData = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.